# OpenLayers 2: Unexpected results from Point.distanceTo()

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I try to use OpenLayers 2 to calculate the distance between Points of a GPS track. I tried using `Point.distanceTo()`, with just the points, and with the points transformed to my map. In both cases I get a result I can't really interpret:

```
var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var pointA = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(5.339911, 60.371876);
var pointB= new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(5.34003, 60.371471);
console.log("raw: " + pointA.distanceTo(pointB));

pointA = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(5.339911, 60.371876).transform(epsg4326, this.map.getProjectionObject());
pointB= new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(5.34003, 60.371471).transform(epsg4326, this.map.getProjectionObject());
console.log("transformed: " + PointA.distanceTo(pointB));
```

gives the following output:

```
raw: 0.0004221208357810271
transformed: 92.1524487013366
```

According to http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html the result should be 45.51 m, which is consistent with my expectations.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the result in a unit I'm not expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([pointA, pointB]);
 console.log("Distance: " +line.getGeodesicLength(epsg4326));
```

this gives you 45,6 (Google Maps gives 46m)

-distanceTo wroks with planar measure (earth is not falt :D)

> Calculate the closest distance between two geometries (on the x-y plane).
>   http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.distanceTo

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that works!  Though I don't think the curvature of the earth matters much over a distance of 45 meters... :-)